# How to handle a non standard delegate in Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab

I am using an assembly from Matlab written in C#. I have gotten many things working, but I ran into one problem. I have a class like this:

```
classdef Mt4Class
% stuff left out
    methods     
    function self = Mt4Class(theIp, thePort) 
        self.IP = theIp;
        self.Port = thePort;
        NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files (x86)\MtApi\MtApi.dll');
        self.apiClient = MtApi.MtApiClient(); 
    end

    function AddListenerQuoteUpdated(self, callback)
        addlistener(self.apiClient, 'QuoteUpdated', callback);
    end

    function MyQuoteUpdate(~, ~, symbol, bid, ask)
        disp(symbol, bid, ask);
    end
end
end
```

I then try the following:

```
mtapi = Mt4Class('', 8222);
mtapi.AddListenerQuoteUpdated(@(~,~, symbol, bid, ask)mtapi.MyQuoteUpdate(0, 0, symbol, bid, ask));
```

However, Matlab comes back with an error:

```
.NET events with nonstandard delegate definition are not supported in MATLAB.
```

I don't have the source to the Api. If I did, it would be simple to package the arguments into an `EventArg`. I could also wrap the API library in my own assembly to refire the event in a `sender, eventargs` form to comply with Matlab, but that seems clunky. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I put some more details in my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears not, I just hit the same issue, but in my case, I do own the DLL that is firing the event.

see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

What you may want to do is to do something like what I am doing.

Basically, you want to make a DLL wrapper that will take both the Bid and Ask values from the original DLL, and then put them in a single object that return that. ExpandoObjects sound great for this, but I doubt they are easy to use inside of Matlab to get values. I use a Dictionary to get object pairs.

Write a simple DLL wrapper that calls the sealed DLL (you can listen to the complex events from the native DLL). Then create a Dictionary in C# and add both the original as dict.Add("core", ddlldata) and then dict.Add("additional", more data).

Then create an event and send this dictionary up to Matlab. You can use the .ITEM("key").Value operation on the .net object in Matlab and get both values.

I can provide code if you want to see an example.

Comment: Do you have any further resources for creating a DLL wrapper for interfacing with Matlab?  Slightly differing from the above description, I have a DLL with a nonstandard delegate definition is being imported into Matlab.  The imported class updates an event when a buffer is ready to be read.  Matlab is refusing to use the listener because the event is not formatted correctly.  Any help in creating a simple wrapper to format the event into a compatible form is greatly appreciated.